# When editing the textarea it is always in motion

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following code that adjusts the size of the textarea dynamically when opening the modal:

```js
$(document)
.on('keyup input keypress keydown change', '.area1', function(e) {
   var tamanhoMin1 =  $(this).attr('rows') * $(this).css('line-height').replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g, '');
   $(this)
   .css({'height': 'auto'});

   var novoTamanho1 = this.scrollHeight + parseFloat($(this).css("borderTopWidth")) + parseFloat($(this).css("borderBottomWidth"));
   if (tamanhoMin1 > novoTamanho1) novoTamanho1 = tamanhoMin1;
   $(this).css({'height': novoTamanho1});
});

$("#add_data_Modal1").on("focus", ()=>$(".area1").keyup());
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary edit_faq" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#add_data_Modal1" style="float: right; margin-left: 1%;">Alterar Procedimento</button>

<div class="modal fade" id="add_data_Modal1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close atualizar" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form action="" method="post" id="faqq1" class="faqq1">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header contact-header">
              <h2 class="text-center">ALTERAR PROCEDIMENTO</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body m- contact-body">
              <div class="form-group mb-0">
                <label for="Procedimento1">Procedimento</label>
                <textarea class="form-control area1" name="Procedimento1" id="Procedimento1" rows="2"> Até pouco tempo atrás todos acreditavam que o Universo era infinito (inclusive a classe científica), nas escolas tal ideia era ensinada nas aulas de geografia, ciências, física entre outras disciplinas afins. O avanço das tecnologias e das próprias técnicas de observação do espaço sideral, acrescido de muito estudo, conduziu a física moderna a derivar outra conclusão sobre o questionamento acerca da extensão do Universo, doravante a esse processo, os físicos criaram um método para calcular o volume cúbico e chegaram ao número que é expresso da seguinte forma: o algarismo 3 e mais 72 zeros.</textarea>               </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, after opening the modal, the textarea adjusts automatically.

The problem is that if I try to edit the text, whenever I type a letter the textarea goes up to the beginning.

How can I solve?

Comment: You're setting the height twice, first to "auto", then to the calculated value. Simply remove the first call.

Comment: @Chris G Thanks, now it works correctly